# VS aborts when printing string array element - c++

Tags: c++, arrays

Printing an element from the array causes an abort. The abort message says invalid null pointer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int day = 5, year = 2015;

    const string months[13] = { 0, "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };

    cout << months[5] << " " << day << ", " << year << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::basic_string<T>(T* arg)` constructor must be called with `arg` pointing to an array of `T`.

You are constructing `std::string` with `0`, thus your `arg` is null pointer. This is undefined behavior (and in Microsoft's implementation, it is checked by `assert` in debug mode; that's why you receiving a debug assertion window).

Example rewritten to show mistake explicitly:

```
char* s = 0;
std::string str(s); // string will try to access null pointer here
```

You must either remove this `0` from array or make it a string literal: `"0"`.

Note, that C++ is a strongly typed language. You can store in arrays only objects of same type or of derived types.

Answer (score 0):

What is `0` doing in your array?

```
const string months[13] = { 0, "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };
                           ^^^
```

Remove it and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Put 0 as string "0".
Here it causes to set the first element of your array as null

Then the iteration to reach the 5th element is interrupted and causes npe